# How to update/create nested object in dynamo

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have few items in DynamoDB like this.

***Example 1 -***

```
{
    "policyName":"Some Name",
    "domainBypassList":{
        "custom":[],
        "default":[]
    }
    "applicationBypassList":{
        "default":{
            "Mac":[],
            "Windows":[]
        },
        "custom":{
            "Mac":[],
            "Window":[]
        }
}
```

***Example 2 -***

```
{
    "policyName":"Some Name",
    "domainBypassList":{
        "default":[]
    }
    "applicationBypassList":{
        "default":{
            "Mac":[],
            "Windows":[]
        }
}
```

I want to add/update the `custom` of `domainBypassList` & `applicationBypassList`. You can see in ***Example 1*** the `custom` attribute exist in both `domainBypassList` & `applicationBypassList`. However, in ***Example 2*** you can see that `custom` attribute is missing. So if the custom attribute is missing then it should be added or if it exist then it should be updated.

I wrote a simple query which works only if the `custom` attribute exist in both `domainBypassList` & `applicationBypassList` i.e ***Example 1***.

```
res = self.service_context.policies.update_item(
            Key={
                'tenantId': self.event["user"]['tenantId'],
                'policyName': self.policy_name
            },
            UpdateExpression="set domainBypassList.custom=:dbl, applicationBypassList.custom=:abl, updatedAt=:uat",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':abl': self.payload["applicationBypassList"],
                ':dbl': self.payload["domainBypassList"],
                ':uat': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %I:%M %p")
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

How can I make this query make work with both the cases.

Here is the object that I have for `custom` of both `domainBypassList` & `applicationBypassList`.

```
{
    "applicationBypassList":{
        "Mac": [
        "Zoom.us",
        "fool.is"
    ],
    "Windows": [
        "Zoom.exe",
        "cool.com"
    ]
    },
    "domainBypassList":["some.com"]
}
```